# Difference between preposition "a" and "de"?

Tags: significado, preposiciones, diferencias-entre-palabras

What is  the  difference between the preposition 'a' and 'de'?

I am not sure if they both  mean 'to/from'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both prepositions can have a lot of different uses, but basically `a` would be "to" and `de` would be "from".

[Preposition `de`](http://dle.rae.es/de)

> Denota de dónde es, viene o sale alguien o algo. La piedra es de Colmenar  <sub>The stone is **from** Colmenar</sub> . Vengo de Aranjuez  <sub>I come from Aranjuez</sub> .

[Preposition `a`](http://dle.rae.es/a)

> Indica la dirección que lleva o el término a que se encamina alguien o algo. Voy a Roma, a palacio  <sub>I'm going **to** Rome, to the palace</sub> . Estos libros van dirigidos a tu padre  <sub>These books are addressed to your father</sub> .

Of course this is a **huge** oversimplification of the many uses of both prepositions.

Comment: Recuerdo que en el colegio siempre me decían (mas o menos) "si usas la palabra definida en la definición, es una mala definición". Aunque definir una preposición debe ser prácticamente imposible siguiendo esa norma.

Answer (score 0):

They mean "to/from", but the correct way to write "to/from" in English is "para" and "de", but in reverse order.

First you will say who is the sender "de" and then you will say who is the receiver "para".

De/Para