# Difference between "salir a" and "salir de"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, preposiciones

Reading the introduction to this article [La Audiencia Nacional abre juicio a Rodrigo Rato y 34 acusados por la salida a Bolsa de Bankia](https://elpais.com/economia/2017/11/17/actualidad/1510923878_046872.html#?ref=rss&format=simple&link=guid) I find the phrase:

> de la causa que investiga la **salida a** Bolsa de la entidad bancaria.

Looking in the DLE I find many (41) definitions for [*salir*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=X42OtRP) but they nearly all use *de* not *a*. The exceptions do not seem to correspond to the meaning here. I take it that the phrase is about the banking organisation leaving the stock exchange, I am not looking for a translation. So my question is why is it not *la salida de la Bolsa*?

There is a Q&A [here](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/12326/difference-between-a-and-de) about the difference between *a* and *de* but that does not help me.

Comment: Se usa la acepción 20 (como en "salir a bailar") pero en un sentido algo más figurado. "Salir a bolsa" es "empezar a cotizar en la bolsa".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Salir a bolsa](https://www.gestion.org/gestion-financiera/mercados-financieros/5814/el-mercado-de-valores-y-salir-a-bolsa/)* is an idiomatic expression, that is, a fixed phrase with a specific meaning that is not totally obvious from the words (like its equivalent in English, *going public*, I guess). It is a well-known phrase in the terminology of financial markets:

> **Salir a bolsa** consiste en un proceso que se orienta a que las acciones de una empresa coticen en la bolsa, es decir, que se puedan
>   comprar y vender de manera libre. Esta acción permite a que personas
>   con ahorros o capital puedan invertir en una empresa para obtener
>   beneficios a medio y largo plazo, aunque siempre teniendo en cuenta el
>   riesgo que supone, y consiste en una acción que permite a la empresa
>   obtener la financiación que necesita.

Although the meaning of the phrase itself is not immediately apparent, the preposition *a* makes sense: together with *salir* it refers to movement "out into" some larger place, often with some purpose. There are many phrases that use *salir a*:

- *salir a jugar* = "go out to play"
- *salir a hablar* = "start to talk"
- *salir al campo* = "go out into the field"
- *salir al sol* = "go outside, under the sun"

There are instances where *salir de* means "to go out and engage in some activity", most of which refer to partying:

- *salir de farra/parranda/joda* = "go out partying"
- *salir de compras* = "go shopping"
- *salir de paseo* = "go take a walk/ride"
- *salir de gira* = "go on a tour"

Because of this usage, where the bare noun following *salir de* refers to certain kinds of activities, it's not likely that *salir de bolsa* would be understood as "go out and offer shares; go public". Instead it would probably be parsed in the same way as the common uses of *salir de* = "go out from, abandon, exit", that is, the exact opposite of the intended meaning.

Comment: Salir de un apuro, salir de compras... no sé si estos ejemplos ayudan.

Comment: *Salir de compras*, por supuesto (y *salir de paseo*). Ya *salir de apuro* es diferente. Gracias!

Comment: That helps to clarify things. In fact I had completely misunderstood the article as being about leaving not joining the exchange.

Answer (score 0):

"Salir a" means that you are going somewhere or you are about to do something,
e.g.:

> *Salir al mercado* = Going to the grocery market
>   *Salir a sacar la basura* = Out to take the trash

"Salir de" means you are getting out of something, like debt or a relationship.

Sometimes both can be used for the same purpose like:

> *Salir a viajar / Salir de viaje* = Going out to travel

Comment: Thank you for your response but I do not feel it adds much to the existing one and if you read my comment on that response you will see that my question was based on a mis-understanding of the whole article anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://www.lawlessspanish.com/vocabulary/expressions/ex-salir.html.

salir a: "to come out to (price)" or "to take after, resemble"

salir de: "to leave" or "to come from (e.g., salt comes from seawater)"

Comment: Thank you for your response but I do not think it adds anything to the existing answer and if you read my comment below it you will see that my question was based on a misreading of the original article.